# SSL sockets get Traffic class do not match in java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, network-programming, serversocket

I am using this [example](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1445603357-A-HTTPS-client-and-HTTPS-server-demo-in-Java) to create SSL sockets but the problem is if i set Traffic class on the client side for example 24 and try to retrieve on the server side using getTrafficClass method, The classes do not match. The server side class is always zero regardless of what i set. I am testing the code on my local machine(mac). I need to have both the classes as the same since this should be the default behavior. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where does it say it should be the default behaviour? Traffic class is whatever you and all the routers and the server agree on. Not something defined by the Java API.

Comment: I agree with that, but the problem is if i set a traffic class of the socket on the client side, it should be the same on the server side as well ? since i am just testing the code on my local machine so we can exclude the routers(network) from the time being.

Comment: Why? The TC isn't a property of the connection, it's a property of the endpoint. It's for outbound traffic.

Comment: @EJP     In other words, what ever value i set for the TC at the client side, i will not be able to get the same value at the server side ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setTrafficClass-int-):

> Sets traffic class or type-of-service octet in the IP header for packets sent from this `Socket.`

There's nothing there about magically propagating the value to the peer `Socket.` It's a property of the local `Socket,` not of the connection. If the peer wants a traffic class for *its* outbound packets, *it* needs to call this method on *its* `Socket`.